# SDL Mobile implementation using Web 8 Delivery DLL

Tags: content-delivery, web8, sdl-mobile

We are using SDL Mobile in our project and after installing Web 8 and using Web 8 Content Delivery DLL's and executing the application, I am getting the following error:

> [Throwable: 
>     java/lang/NoSuchMethodError
>     
>     
>   ]
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowException(Exception ex) +90
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst) +328
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst) +806
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.init() +773
>      Com.Tridion.Ambientdata.Web.RequestValidatorFactory.NewRequestValidator() +34
>      Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.Runtime.AmbientRuntime.Setup() +108
>      Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication application) +59
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +618
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>      System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +402
>      System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +343
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): 
>     java/lang/NoSuchMethodError
>     
>     
>   ]
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +579
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +112
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +716

**Update:** Earlier I referenced Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.dll which throws the above error, Once I removed and add Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.Interop.dll I am getting the following error. Could not load type 'Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule'. I found that for configuring SDL Mobile the following line required  Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule is only avilable in Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.dll Unable to proceed

Comment: I can't comment technically, but with Web 8 you shouldn't be seeing Juggernet messages anymore, as it doesn't need Java/Juggernet. Do you have some code that needs recompiling maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stacktrace contains the magic (and dirty ;o) word **JuggerNET**, which I think indicates you are still refering to DLLs that are pre Web 8.

So you seem to be trying to run something which is using both versions, or is not completely migrated to Web 8.

Comment: Earlier I referenced `Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.dll` which throws the above error, Once I removed and add `Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.Interop.dll` I am getting the following error.      Could not load type 'Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule'. I found that for configuring SDL Mobile the following line required <add type="Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule" name="Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule" />  Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule is only avilable in Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.dll  Unable to proceed

Comment: I think you're mixing versions here. I don't see a `Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.dll` on my webapps in Web 8... Are you using NuGet to get your DLLs? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sdl.Web.Cil/8.2.1

Comment: Since we are not using Web 8 cloud, we are referring them locally.The issue resolved once I removed the refrence and removed Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.Interop.dll, as Bart mentioned Since I used both Interop and new version it created the conflict.

Comment: Even if you are not using SDL Cloud, you can and it is recommended to reference the NuGet package in your project, instead of managing individual DLL references. Did you give it a try?